# Is coffee good or bad for your health?

Tags: nutrition

I am a programmer. I like coffee as it keeps me awake, I usually drink 4 small cups a day.

**I want to know if it is dangerous for your health?** Or in which quantity it should be taken?

Comment: I used to drink coffee all work-day long. I went cold turkey on the caffeine and I felt so much better. No drowsiness and I was able to concentrate better. Of course, I have to have something to drink so I ended up going back to coffee (decaf).

Comment: How is this off topic?!

Comment: Seriously, how is consuming of coffee not a topic for "Fitness and NUTRITION"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Articles Related to this exact question**

- The mayo clinic has a great article answering your question:
  [Is coffee good or bad for me?](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/coffee-and-health/AN01354)
- Also, there's this great article in slate published a few days ago answering this age old debate: [Cafe or Nay](http://www.slate.com/id/2299887)
- USA Today (June 2010): [coffee's endless health debate is grounded in fact](http://www.usatoday.com/news/health/2010-06-14-coffee14_ST_N.htm)

**Mayo Clinic Article**

Anyways here are some interesting findings in Mayo Clinic article:

- Coffee no longer shows any link to cancer / heart disease:

> Recent studies have generally found no connection between coffee and 
>   an increased risk of cancer or heart disease.  Why the apparent
>   reversal in the thinking  about coffee? Earlier studies didn't always
>   take into account that known high-risk  behaviors, such as smoking and
>   physical inactivity, tended to be more common among heavy coffee
>   drinkers at that time.

- Studies show coffee is linked with protecting against Parkinson's, type 2 diabetes and liver cancer because of it's high content of antioxidants:

> Newer studies have also shown that coffee may have benefits, such as
>   protecting against Parkinson's disease, type 2 diabetes and liver
>   cancer. And it has a high content of antioxidants.

- The doctor, Donald Hensrud, in this article indicates that the only downside to coffee is that it doesn't contain any nutrients compared to its counterparts and that you should use coffee in moderation:

> But this doesn't mean you should disregard the old maxim "Everything
>   in moderation." Although coffee may not be very harmful, other
>   beverages such as milk and juice contain nutrients that coffee does
>   not. Also, keep in mind that coffee accompaniments such as cream and
>   sugar add fat and calories to your diet. Finally, heavy caffeine use —
>   on the order of four to seven cups of coffee a day — can cause
>   problems such as restlessness, anxiety, irritability and
>   sleeplessness, particularly in susceptible individuals.

**The Good:**

- Coffee decreases instances of MRSA in a persons nose. A most recent study shows that coffee / tea drinkers are [less likely to carry methicillin-resistant Staphylococcus aureus (MRSA) in their noses](http://methicillin-resistant%20Staphylococcus%20aureus%20%28MRSA%29%20in%20their%20nose). This means coffee / tea have anti-microbiological impacts. However, the link between MRSA and systemic infection have not been linked.
- Coffee Decreases ones risk in Prostate Cancer* [In may](http://jnci.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2011/05/17/jnci.djr151.abstract), Journal of National Cancer Institute found that coffee contains biologically active compounds that can be associated with reduced risk of cancer.
- Long term coffee consumption [reduces risk of type-2 diabetes](http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/news/press-releases/archives/2004-releases/press01052004.html); Indicating Coffee seems to improve insulin sensitivity

Overall, so far the jury is out that coffee can be substantially important in reducing risks of cancer, and various other diseases; just limit your intake.

**The bad:**

- Coffee Drinkers have [20% increased risk of urinary tract cancer](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11369742)
- [Excessive drinking of coffee can increase chances of lung cancer](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19362749) Unfortunately, the abstract indicates that results were inconsistent

**Overall:**

I would just stick to your guns and do what you feel is right. I would continue to consume coffee. It seems as there are a lot of perks of coffee. I would of course, as stated previously, enjoy coffee in moderate amounts.

Comment: No problem. My pleasure. i was curious about this myself.

Comment: Cool answer +1..

Comment: Thanks for the details and references. As an avid coffee drinker (10+ cups per day - mainly espressos), it is nice to know that something good can come from my habit :-)